# Problems when installing the broom package

Tags: r, installation, broom

I can not install the `broom` package. When I try I get this Error Message, that I can't understand:

> - installing *source* package 'broom' ...
>     ** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** using staged installation
>     Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
>     cannot open file 'C:/Users/AndrisLagerlvf/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-broom/00new/broom/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
>     Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
>     cannot open the connection
>     ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'broom'
> - removing 'C:/Users/AndrésLagerlöf/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/broom'
>     Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status

I am using a Widows computer with Windows Version 1909 (OS-version 18363.657), and RStudio Version 1.2.5033, and R version 3.6.2.

When I update some packages it works fine, but when I try to update other packages I get similar error messages as above.

Further notes: I used to have the `broom` package installed, and tried to update the package but when I got the error message I uninstalled the package and then tried to install the package again, but got the same error message, so now I don't have access to the package.

Any suggestions on how to fix would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out/notice the difference between

```
C:/Users/AndrisLagerlvf/Documents/R/win-library/3.6
```

and

```
'C:/Users/AndrésLagerlöf/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/broom
```

That is (international) Encoding showing its ugly face.

I would suggest the following as a solution and also a quite common good practice. 
Create a (most probably local) directory somewhere you have "good" access to that DOES NOT contain any exotic characters (eg C:\R-PKGS\win-library\3.6) then set this as your standard library path

```
.libPaths(c("C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6", .libPaths())) #watch out for the direction of the slashes (normal ones - not backslashes, since this is R code)
```

Put the above line into a/your `~/.Rprofile` file eg via running `file.edit('~/.Rprofile')` in the Console. 
Let me know if that does not help? I am curious because you mentioned that sometimes it works - my guess is that your routine works for those packages that are installed in `R_HOME/library` and not for those installed under your User directory, which contains the exotic characters. Additionally you could minggle around with your locale settings until R is satisfied with them, but I have not tested such a solution (yet) ... since this would involve heavy adjustments, to my locale and typeset settings (sorry for that).

Or even better if you want R to branch according to your Version ie if you have multiple subfolders for multiple differing minor R versions (eg R-3.5 and R-3.6 side by side) ie this is how my libPath setting looks like

```
.libPaths( c( paste0( "D:/R_LIB/", substr(getRversion(),1,3) ), .libPaths() ) )
```

This has the advantage compared to the ENV VAR approach that you can manage multiple R.version library subfolders ...

Comment: Thanks very much @GWD but  I've tried but I think that I may have missed something? I have created the new directory as suggested `C:\R-PKGS\win-library\3.6` but when I run the next command there seems like there is something missing in the command to set library paths, because this is what I get `> file.edit('~/.Rprofile')
> .libPaths(c("C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6", .libPaths())
+ ` so I think that something's missing

Comment: I think that it's now solved! After a bit of googling I change the code for setting libraries to `.libPaths("C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6")` and that seems to work! @GWD thank you again! :)

Comment: Ouch! Seems like R has gone back to old library directory after restarting. The code `.libPaths("C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6")` appears to have worked temporarily but it didn't set the path to the new directory permanently. I don't understand what the `+`-sign at the end really means? Think that R expects something more:  ` 
> .libPaths( c( "C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6"" , .libPaths() ) )
+`

Comment: More googling and after completed changes according to [this link](https://code.adonline.id.au/changing-the-default-library-folder-path-in-r/)  the path seem to have changed to the new directory, even after restarting RStudio!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ... there was a missing paranthesis there that is why you (usually) get + 
Should be `.libPaths( c( "C:/R-PKGS/win-library/3.6", .libPaths() ) )`

Comment: Also it seems I was unprecise regarding what should be written in the Console and what should be written somewhere else. You should type `>file.edit(" ~/.Rprofile)` in the R Console (eg in RStudio) which should open an Editor window with that respective file in it (which is the .Rprofile file in the Users HOME directory). There you should put (copy/paste) the .libPaths(....) command(s) ans save that file. The User Home .Rprofile file should get loaded by R at startup - so the change to your libPath should become permanent that way and not only temporary.

Comment: Tanks again @GWD ! Great help!